# Charts.js: changing xAxis time attribute with function

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a chart built with the Charts.js api. The x axis is configured to show ticks on the hour via moment.js. I would like to give the option to change the X axis ticks from hour to days in the week: I know that to do this I just have to change the code in the Chart from this:

```
    xAxes:
        [{
          type: 'time',
          distribution: 'linear',
          time:
          {
            unit: 'hour'
          }
        }],
```

To this:

```
    xAxes:
        [{
          type: 'time',
          distribution: 'linear',
          time:
          {
            unit: 'week'
          }
        }],
```

But I can't get it to happen with a JavaScript function. I would like to be able to change this setting according to preferences, so I want to build a function that when called will change the "unit" attribute to something different. Can anyone help? Here is what I have so far:

```
function setXAxis()
  {
    chart.config.options.scales.xAxes.time.unit.push('week');
    chart.update();
  };
```

Complete chart.js code:

```
  // Setting up progress chart via Charts.js
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#58a7dd";

  // Configuration
  var chart = new Chart(ctx,
  {
    type: 'line', 
    data: 
    [{
      x: new Date(),
      y: 1
    },
    {
      t: new Date(),
      y: 10
    }],
    options:
    {
      scales:
      {
        xAxes:
        [{
          type: 'time',
          distribution: 'linear',
          time:
          {
            unit: 'hour' //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CHANGE WITH THE FUNCTION
          }
        }],
        yAxes:
        [{
          type: 'category',
          labels: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
        }]
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Update the options of a chart directly with its `options` key, not with `config.options` also `unit` is not array to push, its a key so assign value to it
in your code

```
function setXAxis()  
{
   chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit='week';
   chart.update();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves it. Silly of me to forget the square brackets for the xAxes array too.